# Why connection string is not found or empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

My web.config file is this:

```
 <appSettings>
    ...
    <add key="gvConnString" value="user id = user1; password= pwww333; server= magcian; database= OnB; connection timeout=30" />
    ...
  </appSettings>
```

In my .aspx page I use it like this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsPopulateDepartment" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:gvConnString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM HERECOMES"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I get the following error:

`Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The connection name 'gvConnString' was not found in the applications configuration or the connection string is empty.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are putting your connection string in the `<appSettings>` element. It needs to be in the `<connectionStrings>` element - they are different.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="gvConnString" connectionString="..."/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Wow thank you. I was following a website which was obviously wrong :/